# UIlabel width set to fit on content text

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uilabel

Created a UILabel

```
            lbl_Username = new UILabel {
                Text = "Username",
                Font = UIFont.FromName (DrugHub.Constants.K_HELVETIC_BOLD, KFontSize12),
            };
// Frame the label
            lbl_Username.Frame = new RectangleF (40, 20, 100, 12);
View.addSubView(lbw_Username.Frame);
```

How to set frame width size "auto". Size to fit on text content.

currently using Username for label  and set label.width = 100,

label.width need to set automatically adjust according to content inside the Label.Text.

@All 
Thanks In advance.

Comment: After posting question:: i figure out the answer. lbl_Username.AttributedText.Size.Width.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGSize size = [string sizeWithAttributes:
                       @{NSFontAttributeName:
                         [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}];
```

[Replacement for deprecated sizeWithFont: in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7)

[Dynamically resize label in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029018/dynamically-resize-label-in-ios-7)

[Dynamically getting height of UILabel according to Text return different Value for iOS 7.0 and iOS 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068849/dynamically-getting-height-of-uilabel-according-to-text-return-different-value-f)

this link help you.